# Transferring large amount of files, using ftpdmin.exe, can this be parallelized?

Tags: ftp

Every now and then, I need to transfer about 60,000+ files (source tree) between two computers on a LAN.  I found this nice utility FTPDMIN.exe from http://www.sentex.net/~mwandel/ftpdmin/ which basically starts an FTP server from the command line to some specified root dir.  This works nicely, I can use FileZilla from the client and start uploading my source to the target machine, very convenient.

However, the overall network transfer is a bit slow, I would like to run multiple transfers at the same time (to maximize network throughput), thus reducing the time to copy so many files.

This app is from 2004...

1)  Is there a way (or even different comparable, easy-to-run app) that can use multiple threads at the server so as to maximize network usage?

2)  Is there a newer version of this app anywhere?  It did give up after awhile and had a small number of failed transfers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try **RichCopy**, it's a high-performance, multi-threaded Windows copy app - from Microsoft - and it's free!

http://www.pkguild.com/2009/08/introducing-richcopy-your-robocopy-replacement/

Comment: Thanks Ms./Mr. 2D barcode (really want to decode that), this looks most promising, I will be giving it a spin for my next file transfer.  BTW who is "Rich" and why do I want to copy 'im? ;-)